# Regular expression to match all non-alphanumerics except apostropes in contractions

Tags: regex, tokenize, alphanumeric, non-alphanumeric

I'm trying to tokenize a string of English text such that I can get a sequence of the words without any punctuation, but at the same time I want to leave contractions (like *don't* and *won't*) and possessive nouns (like *Steve's* and *Drew's*) intact. I'm trying to pull this off using regular expressions, but I'm still new to them.

Basically, I want a regular expression that will match all sequences of non-alphanumeric characters except for apostrophes which are surrounded by alphanumeric characters such as in the examples mentioned previously. Is it possible to do this with regular expressions?

Comment: What about [\w']+ or [a-zA-Z']+ to match the words you want, with '. After you match, it depends on your language for details of how the split should return those words.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what your regex is trying to match, but I think this will match what you want:

```
(?i)(?<=^|\s)([a-z]+('[a-z]*)?|'[a-z]+)(?=\s|$)
```

This matches "words" that may optionally end with an apostrophe followed by 0-n letters, or an apostrophe followed by letters, which matches the following edge cases:

- Thing
- Jack's
- Ross'
- 'tis

Answer (score 0):

Your question not very clear to me. But If I interpreted correctly, following regex should do the job

```
\b[\w']+\b
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/tR0cP8)

Comment: This won't match "Ross'" which is the correct spelling for the possessive of a noun ending in "s" (ie you don't write "Ross's"), so you can't use `\b` at the end, nor the front due to "'twas" and "'tis"